# Sentinel container fails with error Unrecognized sentinel configuration statement

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-sentinel

I have a k8s deployment for a Redis cluster with 3 Sentinels replicas and 3 slaves. I am facing an error on one of the sentinel pods :

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 6.2.3) ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 4
>>> 'sentinel monitor mymaster  6379 2'
Unrecognized sentinel configuration statement.
```

My sentinel manifest is as below :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sentinel
  namespace: demos
spec:
  serviceName: sentinel
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sentinel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sentinel
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: config
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
        args:
          - |
            REDIS_PASSWORD=a-very-complex-password-here
            nodes=redis-0.redis,redis-1.redis,redis-2.redis

            for i in ${nodes//,/ }
            do
                echo "finding master at $i"
                MASTER=$(redis-cli --no-auth-warning --raw -h $i -a $REDIS_PASSWORD info replication | awk '{print $1}' | grep master_host: | cut -d ":" -f2)
                if [ "$MASTER" == "" ]; then
                    echo "no master found"
                    MASTER=
                else
                    echo "found $MASTER"
                    break
                fi
            done
            echo "sentinel monitor mymaster $MASTER 6379 2" >> /tmp/master
            echo "port 5000
            sentinel resolve-hostnames yes
            sentinel announce-hostnames yes
            $(cat /tmp/master)
            sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 5000
            sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
            sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
            sentinel auth-pass mymaster $REDIS_PASSWORD
            " > /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
            cat /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
      containers:
      - name: sentinel
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command: ["redis-sentinel"]
        args: ["/etc/redis/sentinel.conf"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          name: sentinel
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
      - name: redis-config
        emptyDir: {}
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "cinder-csi"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sentinel
  namespace: demos
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
    name: sentinel
  selector:
    app: sentinel
```

And the redis manifest :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: demos
spec:
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: config
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
        args:
          - |
            cp /tmp/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
            
            echo "finding master..."
            MASTER_FDQN=`hostname  -f | sed -e 's/redis-[0-9]\./redis-0./'`
            if [ "$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 ping)" != "PONG" ]; then
              echo "master not found, defaulting to redis-0"

              if [ "$(hostname)" == "redis-0" ]; then
                echo "this is redis-0, not updating config..."
              else
                echo "updating redis.conf..."
                echo "slaveof $MASTER_FDQN 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
              fi
            else
              echo "sentinel found, finding master"
              MASTER="$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | grep -E '(^redis-\d{1,})|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})')"
              echo "master found : $MASTER, updating redis.conf"
              echo "slaveof $MASTER 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
            fi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
        - name: config
          mountPath: /tmp/redis/
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:6.2.3-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command: ["redis-server"]
        args: ["/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
          name: redis
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
        - name: redis-config
          mountPath: /etc/redis/
      volumes:
      - name: redis-config
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: redis-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "cinder-csi"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 50Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: demos
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis
```

And from k8s I have :

```
kubectl -n demos get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
redis-0                               1/1     Running            0          3h3m
redis-1                               1/1     Running            0          23m
redis-2                               1/1     Running            0          23m
sentinel-0                            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   40         3h3m
sentinel-1                            1/1     Running            0          126m
sentinel-2                            1/1     Running            0          8m33s
```

I have extracted logs for redis-2 also :

```
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.924 # Server initialized
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.925 * Ready to accept connections
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.925 * Connecting to MASTER redis-0.redis.labs.svc.myserver-XXX:XXXX
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.947 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.947 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.947 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.951 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:46.954 * Full resync from master: 6b11d6e184b481e9112053er6575790dhjdj782:55557
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.038 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 178 bytes from master to disk
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.038 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Flushing old data
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.044 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Loading DB in memory
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.052 * Loading RDB produced by version 6.2.3
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.052 * RDB age 1 seconds
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.052 * RDB memory usage when created 1.89 Mb
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.053 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: Finished with success
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.053 * Background append only file rewriting started by pid 11
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.091 * AOF rewrite child asks to stop sending diffs.
11:C 26 May 2022 13:58:47.091 * Parent agreed to stop sending diffs. Finalizing AOF...
11:C 26 May 2022 13:58:47.091 * Concatenating 0.00 MB of AOF diff received from parent.
11:C 26 May 2022 13:58:47.091 * SYNC append only file rewrite performed
11:C 26 May 2022 13:58:47.091 * AOF rewrite: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.154 * Background AOF rewrite terminated with success
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.154 * Residual parent diff successfully flushed to the rewritten AOF (0.00 MB)
1:S 26 May 2022 13:58:47.154 * Background AOF rewrite finished successfully
```

I am not quite sure why the other replica for sentinel is failing.

What am I missing?

Comment: found anything ?

Comment: you can use "https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis-cluster" or "https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/redis-cluster", it is quite good, and no error on my tries

Answer (score 1):

I remember i was in same situation. Kindly lets follow the process:

1. The init container `config` starts and configures sentinel
2. The sentinel container starts and uses the config file generated by init container.

This means sentinel is reporting what was misconfigured by init container. Let's go back to init container. Why does `'sentinel monitor mymaster  6379 2'` line have no master, none was found, however, the init container continued with the configuration without the master address. That's the problem.

What's the solutions?

1. My Solution: Fail the init container before it passes the configuration to sentinel container. That means the init container will keep restarting until it finds a master, then proceed to sentinel container. I implemented a simple check in init container after the loop:

```
            if [ "$MASTER" = "" ]; then
              echo "Sorry! No master was found!"
              echo "Exiting..."
              # Exit with code 1, to simulate an error,
              # This will force the init container to restart 
              # untill it finds a master.
              exit 1
            fi
```

2. Some posts suggest adding a `startup probe` to probe redis network. This ensures that the sentinel containers will be initiliazed when the redis network is ready. To me i like quick solution i did not implement this. Check this post: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/9296